# launching Chrome from Mac terminal with options

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal

I want to launch a special instance of Chrome from Mac Terminal, e.g.

```
open -a "Google Chrome.app" --args --incognito --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

It works fine, but only if Chrome is not already running. Otherwise it uses the running window, not even opening a new tab and no args are passed.
Using Big Sur 11.7.4, Chrome Version 111.0.5563.146.
Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --incognito --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Comment: it works great! tnx